# parseFloat() inside forEach() not working

Tags: javascript, foreach, functional-programming, parsefloat

can anyone help me understand why this code doesn't work? Don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
let ratings = ["8.8", "8.6", "9.0", "8.3"];

ratings.forEach(rating => {
return parseFloat(rating)}
);
```

I just get undefined.

Comment: note that forEach returns undefined so use Array.map() instead.

Comment: `forEach` is an optimized `map` since its only for side effects and returned values are never used. `ubdefined` is correct result.

Comment: `console.log(ratings.map(Number))`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program is not working since your `forEach()` is not storing the result anywhere. And it would be better to use 
[Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) in this case :

:

```js
let ratings = ["8.8", "8.6", "9.0", "8.3"];

ratings = ratings.map(a=> parseFloat(a));

console.log(ratings);
```